# RDS Terminal server profile migration

Tags: terminal-server, rds, roaming-profile

I need help with RDS profile migration.

We have 2 domains. Domain A and Domain B. Our terminal server is in Domain A and user profile created in file server (different location) as roaming profile.

Both domains have two way trust existing and all the users from Domain A copied to Domain B with SID history.

We want to allow Domain B users to login into terminal server environment and need to map same VHDX to Domain B users (same users from Domain A).

I tried to rename SID name in my test environment on VHDX profile and it working fine but when I am doing in production with test user I am getting "group policy client service failed" error when I am login. There are no issue with group policy on domain A as I tried without group policy as well.

What i am doing wrong.